# How to check if the user is in an application on android?

Tags: android, android-intent, widget, android-service

I'm making an animated clock widget for Android and I would like to optimse the refreshing process by stoping it when the clock is not visible.

To do so, I want to check if the user is on the home screen or inside an application. I also need to receive the "back on home screen" event if possible. I don't know how to do that.

For now, I'm running my widget within a sticky Service and I've already implemented a "screen on/off" receiver.

Comment: Optionnaly, I would like to do the same with the different home screens : refresh the clock only when the user goes on a screen containing the widget (like the clock on HTC Hero).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [ActivityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) to get a list of running tasks, then check which package the most recent one belongs to. However:

1. Google warns against this in their own docs
2. This would require you to declare the `android.permission.GET_TASKS` permission in your Manifest, and I'm sure potential users will find it odd that a clock widget wants to know what tasks are running.

Assuming you did this, you may then be able to tell whether it is a Launcher app by checking whether anything in that package can resolve an `Intent` defined this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
```

Without using ActivityManager, I don't know of any way to discern which application is in front of the user at any given moment. Outside of your own app, there is also no way to know what `Activity` within that app is in front of the user at any given moment.

> Optionnaly, I would like to do the same with the different home screens : refresh the clock only when the user goes on a screen containing the widget

It's worth mentioning that the Launcher app may not be using separate Activities for individual home screens (and in fact none of the launchers that I have examined do this). Even if it did use separate activities, you wouldn't know which screen your widget is on, unless that app somehow exposes that information to you (highly unlikely).

Overall, I'd say you have a lot working against you to optimize your clock widget. At best you may be able to tell which app is in front of the user and whether it is a Launcher.

Answer (score 0):

You should override [onPause(](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29)) and [onResume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29) methods of your activity. Hope this helps.